# Vue: Passing a link to components prob

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

why does this doesn't work?

Child-Component:

```
<template>
    <button class="btn" @click="router.push('{{link}}')">{{ text }}</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const router = useRouter();

const props = defineProps({
    text: String,
    link: String,
})

</script>
```

Parent-Component:

`

```
<Button text="To MainView" link="'/mainview'"></Button>
```

`

Passing text works, passing link also shows the right String in Console (/mainview) but the link it shows me is http://localhost:8080/%7B%7Blink%7D%7D.

And now I'm confused because in my understanding it should work. Thanks!

Comment: why are you even abstracting a button into a component?

Comment: Because two buttons will be in the component and I'll reuse it many times. So I don't wanna have the code in every single component

Answer (score 1):

In your code, this line `@click="router.push('{{link}}')"` don't work like that.  You can write like this

```
@click="$router.push(`${link}`)"
```

Vue Mustache syntex i.e `{{}}` only work inside HTML tag like

```
<div>{{val}}</div>
```

to call an event you can simply run like below

```
<div @click="any valid js syntex">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. This javascript syntax is killing me.

Comment: You are welcome. And use `$router.push()` in the template instead of `router.push()` I have updated my and.

Answer (score 0):

You've already defined `link` as a static prop in your Child Component so you don't have to add single quotes around `/mainview`:

```html
<Button text="To MainView" link="/mainview"></Button>
```

It would only be necessary if the prop is a dynamic prop (ex. `:link="'/mainview'"`) but in this case, since you're defining `/mainview` directly into the prop then you can omit the single quotes ([Static Props vs Dynamic props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)). Additionally, you can pass `link` directly to the `@click` event like so:

```html
<button class="btn" @click="router.push(link)">{{ text }}</button>
```

or just use [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#router-link) instead:

```html
<router-link :to="link">
    <button class="btn">{{ text }}</button>
</router-link>
```